# How to make a slideshow being autoplay when in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm building a slideshow for a client, and he wants it, upon page load, to be in the paused state, and not start autoplaying until the user is viewing the area of the page that the slideshow exists in. Any ideas on how I can make this happen? I'm truly at a loss of where to even being on this, so if someone can just point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "inview" event jQuery plugin might help you: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Comment: is it in some place in the page and you need to "scroll" for example to see the animation ?

Comment: @ImadBakir Yes, you need to scroll down in order to get to the animation.

Comment: @benhowdle89 this was incredibly helpful for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use scroll event handler, whenever scroll action fires you execute a check
Here you are try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) { //supposing your element is on 500
            alert(1); //or do whatever
        }
    });
```

and if you need to repeat the motion on every time the user comes to the desired part you can for example use the same mechanism:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) { //for instance 
            //re-arrange your stuff 
        }
    });
```

[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
>   are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is
>   at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will
>   be

here is a [demo](http://benseno.com.tr/demo/cars1/)

Comment: What exactly is the "100" denoting? Pixel height?

Comment: @ignu5_ , yes it's pixels, I edited the answer with `.scrollTop()` explanation

Comment: @ignu5_ here is a demo, I did the same thing once:
http://benseno.com.tr/demo/cars1/

Comment: Thank you. This combined with remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin is everything I needed. You guys rock!

Answer (score -1):

You can detect where the user has scrolled to using the scroll event handler:

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function(e) {
    var currentPosition = $window.scrollTop();
    var slideshowPosition = 100,
        slideshowHeight = 200;
    if (currentPosition > slideshowPosition &&
        currentPosition < slideshowPosition + slideshowHeight) {
        // play slideshow here
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Nevermind! You'll actually have to use scrollTop() to get the scrolled position.

EDIT: I've amended the code above to get the scroll position.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ it's a start point.